# PyTorch find optimal scalar that used in weigted sum of model parameters

Tags: pytorch, derivative, autograd

I have a similar problem. Can I ask you a question?

I try to extend it. I create two frozen model with two layers. frozen1, frozen2: nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5,5), nn.Linear(5,5)) and weighted average with variable c (torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.float32))

In order to find optimal c that minimize the loss of the model

```
for p_out, p_in1, p_in2 in zip(self.model.parameters(), self.frozen1.parameters(), self.frozen2.parameters()):
    p_out = p_in1 + self.c * p_in2
```

However, it outputs when loss.backward(). could you help?

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[248], line 64
     62 print(loss)
     63 optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 64 loss.backward()
     65 # optimizer.step()
     66 for n,p in frozen1.named_parameters():


File ~/anaconda3/envs/debug/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:
    307, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs) 
    298 if has_torch_function_unary(self): 
    299 return handle_torch_function( 
    300 Tensor.backward, 
    301 (self,), (...) 
    305 create_graph=create_graph, 
    306 inputs=inputs) --> 307 torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/debug/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/init.py:
    154, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs) 
    151 if retain_graph is None: 
    152 retain_graph = create_graph --> 
    154 Variable.execution_engine.run_backward( 
    155 tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs, 
    156 allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I tried weighted sum of frozen(requires_grad=False) model, get partial derivative of c.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import copy

class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, frozen1, frozen2):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.frozen1 = frozen1
        self.frozen2 = frozen2
        self.model = copy.deepcopy(frozen1)
        self.c = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1, dtype=torch.float32))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        for p_out, p_in1, p_in2 in zip(self.model.parameters(), self.frozen1.parameters(), self.frozen2.parameters()):
            print('p_out:',p_out,'\n p_in1:', p_in1)
            p_out = p_in1 + self.c * p_in2
            print('p_out:',p_out)
        
        return self.model(x) 
    
frozen1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5, 5), nn.Linear(5, 5))
for p in frozen1.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False
frozen2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5, 5), nn.Linear(5, 5))
for p in frozen2.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False

model = Net(frozen1, frozen2)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
x = torch.rand(5).unsqueeze(0)
y = torch.tensor([0]*4+[1], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)

out = model(x)
loss = criterion(out, y)
print(loss)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()

for n,p in frozen1.named_parameters():
    print(p)
for n,p in frozen2.named_parameters():
    print(p)
```